# How do I specify destroy path helper in a view of my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model Category in my Rails app. According to rails RESTful Routes, I can perform CRUD Operations on model, having `resources: categories`  defined in my routes.rb.

But how do i define destroy path helper in my view to perform `DELETE` action, just like `edit_category_path(@category)` to edit the record. I tried like this
 `destroy_category_path(@category)` but getting error as

```
undefined method `destroy_category_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000005371298>:0x000000053734f8>
```

Comment: Put yor full code on how you're trying to call the destroy method? It's a link_to?

Comment: for example: link_to 'destroy', category_path, methdo: :delete

Comment: yes. like this <%= link_to "Delete", destroy_category_path(@category) %>. But i've even tired using a form still didn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The path is exactly the same as the show action (['/categories/:id'](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)), but you also need to specify the `DELETE` [HTTP method](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp):

```
button_to @category, method: :delete
```

Note, it is not considered safe to use links having destructive/constructive actions, as those might be visited by robots.

Comment: You can, but you should be slightly more cautious.

Comment: is there any path helper to do this simply?

Comment: Path helper will give you a path. Path itself does not include a verb. Varb can only be changed by the element using the path like link or button. Hence there is no way to do this just with a path helper.

Comment: I guess it is `method: :delete`

Comment: @bhanua1 - Sorry, not getting the last comment? What is `method: :delete`?

Comment: when i used `button_to @category, method: :destroy`, i am getting `No route matches [POST]`, then after i used a form `<%= form_for @category, url: category_path, method: :delete %>` and it worked. Sorry if confused you as as i am a beginner.

Comment: @bhanua1 - Which rails version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

There is a path helper for delete, but Rails defaults to having this route not defined. To activate the helper you need to add delete to your resourceful routes in your routes.rb file.

```
resources :categories do
    member do
       get :delete
    end
end
```

Once you've done that you should be able to use `delete_category_path(@category)`.

Then inside your category you can call destroy on the object from your delete action.